# Change workspace directory of eclipse to www

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, eclipse, workspace

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed.

I have Eclipse Indigo installed.

I have LAMP installed, with the localhost being /var/www.

However, my Eclipse workspace location is /workspace.

How can I change it to /var/www same as localhost for the reasons of when I set up a project, the folder automatically is viewable via localhost on the browser.

I have tried just setting up a second workspace to /var/www. But it gives me the error:

```
The folder /var/www/.metadata is read-only
```

Comment: probably a permissions issue. and i dont want to suggest chmod 777. it probably works, but is not advisable.

Comment: as i said, its not advisable. i'll find better info and will answer shortly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a permissions issue. There are several workarounds for that.

1. `sudo chmod 777 /var/www` : Works definitely if its a permissions issue, but to be used with caution. It is not advisable, since that would be compromising security.
2. `ls -l /var |grep www` , look at the group, and add yourself to that group, and then `sudo chmod g+rwx /var/www`. you may also create a new group and add yourself to it, then `sudo chgrp <newGrp> /var/www` and then `sudo chmod g+rwx /var/www`
3. `sudo chown <yourUserName> /var/www` : Better than 777'ing, but not so elegant.

If you have a choice, I recommend the second one. Its the most elegant way.